# Is using android:view_state constant considered a good practice?

Tags: android, view, viewstate

Currently I'm using `android:view_state` constant to retrieve `SparseArray` with views states.

It is reccomended way to do this or I should put my separate values to `Bundle` (eg. position of `ViewPager`)?

Comment: hmm, err, it depends on... but actually what are you talking about?

Comment: I would like to save position of my `ViewPager`, should I use built-in   `Bundle` or use my custom value key-value pair?

Comment: ok, and whats wrong with a buil-in Bundle?

Comment: @pskink Constants are not public, nor are documented anywhere in the official documentation.

Comment: ok, are we talking about onSaveInstanceState / onRestoreInstanceState ?

Comment: @pskink Yes - I mean getting view states using this constant.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use `VIEW_STATE_TAG`: "android:view_state"?
Check below article. It explains how you should save a state of your own view.
https://trickyandroid.com/saving-android-view-state-correctly/

You can extend ViewPager and override `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` to achieve that.